# How to request app info from Google Play store without authentication

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, version

I've done some research and stumbled across the following (maybe unofficial) url which is used to query app details from android play store. But based on the unofficial google market api I guess this one *is* using authentication token

```
http://android.clients.google.com/market/api/ApiRequest
```

There is obviously a way to request android app details without logging into ones google account - that's how Google play site works when browsed in a web browser.

I was unable to find any guidance on how to actually do that.

The project I develop cannot have any unofficial libraries or codes in it, it also cannot use any private android API.

I also came up to the following link, which obviously is not an official google api link (in other words not 100% trustworthy that it wouldn't change without prior notice)

```
https://androidquery.appspot.com/api/market?app=(put the package name here)
```

But I guess any possible solution should be something similar to what this link is internally performing.

So, how to construct a valid request to google play store to retrieve app info (request url, parameters, parameter formats, cookies, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I have google a bit to this interesting case.

The short answer is, there is no easy API to get this info.
You need to do some work to get clean data.

This will be usefull:
[Is there an official API for the Google Play Store app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017291/is-there-an-official-api-for-the-google-play-store-app)

https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

[Get app-details from Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354816/get-app-details-from-google-play)

Hope this helps :).